# Search in DataGridView giving error

Tags: c#, postgresql, datagridview

I'm trying to search employees by Name.
Of course, there can be same Names for different employees.

I want my function to highlight all the employees with the Name i entered.

If i use `break;` i will get only the first value found, if I don't use `break;` I get all values but I also get the `Error: Object reference not set to an instance of object.`

Here is the full code:

```
    // SAMEKLET DARBINIEKU
    private void btn_mekletDarbinieku_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchValue = txt_mekletDarbinieku.Text;

        DGV_darbinieks.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV_darbinieks.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                {
                    row.Selected = true;
                    //break; // šito varētu izmantot personas kodam, jo tāds tik viens būtu
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What object is it saying is null when you get that exception?  And on which specific line?

Comment: That's all what is says "Object reference not set to an instance of object.". It's a popup window when it catches the error.

Comment: You'd need to either get rid of your try/catch and see exactly what the exception is saying or put a breakpoint on that method and step through to see the details of said exception.  My best guess is that it's giving you an error on that if statement because that row.Cell[1] has no value or there is no second column.  You just need to use some basic debugging to solve issues like this.